# Angular 13 and Bootstrap 5 | UI vanishes when routes are added

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, bootstrap-5, angular13

I have been developing a website for a moment but haven't been able to move past the nav. The issue I am having is that when I set up a route the entire UI vanishes and will not load. I have not been able to find anything on this or why it may be happening but any sort of help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

**navi.component.html**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light bg-gradient shadow rounded">
    <div class="container-xxl ">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">
            <span class="fw-bold">
                207 Tech Services
            </span>
        </a>
        <!-- Toggle button mobile nav -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler text-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
        data-bs-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end align-center" id="main-nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav fw-light">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a routerLink="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: '/home', component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './components/portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { NaviComponent } from './components/navi/navi.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    NaviComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-navi></app-navi>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "techservices",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "techservices": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/techservices",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "techservices:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "techservices:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "techservices:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "techservices"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app-routes.module.ts`, you should not use `/` on the route path definition; i.e., use `home` instead of `/home`.

In your `navi.component.html`, the `href` directive in Angular refreshes the page. Please update all `href` directives with `routerLink` directive in the `a` tag of the `nav` bar.

Comment: The `/` was the issue! Thank you so much!